# Transparency on Focused/Unfocused windows

Tags: xmonad

Instead of using borders, I want to set the alpha of focused and unfocused windows to, say, 90% and 70%. This would apply to all windows except those matching some criterion like className = "Gimp". How can I implement this in my xmonad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [XMonad.Hooks.FadeInactive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Hooks-FadeInactive.html). Note that it requires [Xcompmgr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xcompmgr) or something of a kind.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib/docs/XMonad-Hooks-FadeInactive.html